# Angular Mouse Directives on Touch Devices

Tags: angularjs, touch

I have a simple web game working in HTML5 and CSS with Angular.  It's using Angular's ng-mousedown, ng-mousemove, and ng-mouseup directives to let the user highlight letters and tiles in the game and "swipe" around from side to side.

Works great on a desktop in a browser.  However, in mobile Safari on an iPad or iPhone, none of the mouse actions seem to trigger properly - instead of affecting game elements, the touch actions just try to pan and zoom the browser window itself.

I have kept jQuery out of my solution thus far.  I have used jQuery-touch-punch to get jQUery-UI's drag and drop working on mobile Safari before.  But what is a jQuery-less solution?  I just want the app to behave in the same way that it does on desktop browsers.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[ngTouch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch) sounds like the module you want. `ngClick` is an abstraction of jQuery clicks to support both mouse and touch events. If you want to highlight something while the user is pressing down, this snippet might be helpful from the docs:

> This directive also sets the CSS class ng-click-active while the element is being held down (by a mouse click or touch) so you can restyle the depressed element if you wish.

Moreover, `ngSwipeLeft` and `ngSwipeRight` allow setting up swipe event callbacks.

However, it sounds like your game may require more complex behavior than simply binding to these 3 directives. If you use create your own directive and use the `$swipe` service, you can probably have a lot finer control over the behavior.

Comment: That looks cool, except - does it only support horizontal swipes, and not vertical?  That seems beyond belief to me.

Comment: The `$swipe` service supports both. From the docs (linked in my answer): "Once this threshold is exceeded, either the horizontal or vertical delta is greater. - If the horizontal distance is greater, this is a swipe and move and end events follow. - If the vertical distance is greater, this is a scroll, and we let the browser take over."